# how to find empty value for specific key in multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i have array like this

```
<?php
$array =
    array
    (
        array (
            0 => 1,
            1 => 'php',
            2 => 11,
            3 => 11,
            4 => 11,
            5 => 11,
            6 => 11,
        ),
        array (
            0 => 1,
            1 => 'php',
            2 => 11,
            3 => 11,
            4 => 11,
            5 => 11,
            6 => ,
        ),

    );
```

and i want to search in this multi-array to find if the key  [6] =>  is empty.if it was empty in any array return false so how to do this

```
foreach($array as $item)
{
    foreach($item as $key=>$value)
    {
        print($key);
        if($key=="6" && $value==NULL)
        {
            echo "found";
            return false;
        }else{
            echo "not found";
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/rianrainey/4263778)

Comment: check this out http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: What's wrong with what you have written?

Comment: it is not search correctly

Comment: it is should give me found message because i have empty value in key 6 but it is not give me this message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$empty = false;
foreach($array as $item)
{
    if(empty($item[6]))
    {
            $empty=true;
            break;
    }
}
return $empty;
```

Comment: if condition is not closed

Comment: @RubinAnbin fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- First, it's recommended to use only one `return` in a function, so define a boolean value, and turn it to TRUE when the condition satisfies.
- Second, use `break` to stop the cycle(s) running (saves runtime)
  http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php
- Third, check keys and values appropriately. Your keys are numeric and you are comparing to a string "6". Use empty() if you are interested in that the value is an empty-ish value. Be aware that a numeric zero is an empty value. If you are specifically interested in NULL value, use === operator
  http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php
  http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php
- +1 See Yoda-style conditions
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions
- ++1 Use K&R style indent, or don't use it. But do not try! ;)
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style

  ```
  $found = false;
  foreach ($array as $item) {
      foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
          print($key);
          if (6 == $key && NULL === $value) { // or use 'empty($value)'
              echo "found";
              $found = true;
              break 2;
          } else {
              echo "not found";
          }
      }
  }
  return !$found;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate for PHP >= 5.5.0 that checks for `''`, `0`, `null` and `false`:

```
return !array_diff($six = array_column($array, 6), array_filter($six));
```